# App Registration of Owned App Not Listed In Enterprise Applications on Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I've registered the B2C SAML app with the help from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

I'd like to try Idp initiated sign-in using myapplications.onmicrosoft.com, but I could not find the my SAML app on myapplications list. I guess the reason being that "App registration" based SAML application is not displaying under B2C tenant active directory "Enterprise Applications" blade. In Idp Initiated myapplications.onmicrosoft.com will only shows the apps icons of enterprise applications list? So...

1. Why Azure AD B2C "App registrations" - owned SAML application is not listing under B2C tenant enterprise applications? Is this expected behaviour?
2. If I need to use Idp initiated sign-in page for my B2C SAML application, what would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second question, it's described [Options for registering a SAML application in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

You need to set:

```
<Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item>
```

and the URL is of the form:

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/generic/login?EntityId=app-identifier-uri
```

Comment: Thanks rbrayb, For our initial business requirements, we only allow B2C AD local accounts to access our SAML application. It seems above "<Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item>" is required for non-local social federated accounts custom policies?  From MS Ref: We don't currently support scenarios where the initiating identity provider is an external identity provider federated with Azure AD B2C, for example AD-FS, or Salesforce. It is only supported for Azure AD B2C local account authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is expected.

The federation style app registration(Saml or ws-Federation) is intended to provide Idp for old Apps(Saml or ws-Federation) living in other realm. As they has nothing to do with the AAD B2c, Enterprise application (local representation or service principal of the app) is not needed. Also they are pretty old protocol comparing to oath2/openid connect.

So in AAD world, you want to register you app using the default app registration, where you can choice single tenant(an enterprise application will be automatically created in the same tenant) or multiple tenant(manually create enterprise application in each tenant) and you use oath2/openid connect to initiate login.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0

.

Comment: Thanks Larry, its helpful.